# I have DIV and its child DIV , i want to select last DIV using jQuery . Parent DIVS have id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the description of problem  . I have parent div(allcomments_4) and than inside it , i have few child divs(oneEntry) with their own children inside but i just need to find the last child of the parent node(allComments_4). I want to read the content inside of div(lastComment) it than add it above this div which will be similar like above div (oneEntry) using jquery. I want to do this manipulation using ids not class. As i calculate the id of allComments_4 div . I tried like this.

```
<script>
    var allcommentsId =allcomments_4
    var right = "div#lastComment"
    var left = '#'+allcommentsId 
    var message = $(left>right ).html()
    alert(message)
</script>

<div id="allcomments_4">
 <div class="oneEntry">
   <div class="commentImage">
   </div>
   <div class="commentEntry">
   <div class="commentText">
   </div>
   <div class="commentDate">
    Commented On -"Thu Jan 26 16:44:16 EST 2012"/>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="oneEntry">
   <div class="commentImage">
   </div>
   <div class="commentEntry">
   <div class="commentText">
   </div>
   <div class="commentDate">
    Commented On -"Thu Jan 26 16:44:16 EST 2012"/>
   </div>
 </div>
</div><!-- One Comment Entry Ends here -->
<div id ="lastComment">
</div><!-- last Comment ends here -->
</div><!-- All Comments Ends here -->
```

I think missing something and i am sorry for asking such lame question as i am beginner in jquery and this whole javascript thing.

Comment: ` id="oneEntry"` You know that IDs are unique?

Comment: you can't use multiple id with the same name. Also in the first var you have to change the value to `"allcomments_4"` because now it recognize it as an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var message = $(left>right ).html()
```

This does not work as it gives the result of the bigger than comparison as parameter. It has to look like this:

```
var message = $(left + ' > ' + right).html()
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, IDs must be unique. That being said, here is a way to accomplish what you asked (using classes where appropriate):

```
function displayContent(IdNum) {
    var Id = '#allcomments_' + IdNum;
    var $lastComment = $(Id).find('.lastComment');
    var message = $lastComment.html();
    alert(message);
}

displayContent(4);
```

HTML w/ classes (for reference):

```
<div id="allcomments_4">
    <div class="oneEntry">
        <div class="commentImage">
        </div>
        <div class="commentEntry">
            <div class="commentText">
            </div>
            <div class="commentDate">
            Commented On - "Thu Jan 26 16:44:16 EST 2012"
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oneEntry">
        <div class="commentImage">
        </div>
        <div class="commentEntry">
            <div class="commentText">
            </div>
            <div class="commentDate">
            Commented On - "Thu Jan 26 16:44:16 EST 2012"
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- One Comment Entry Ends here -->
    <div class="lastComment">
        Body of lastComment
    </div><!-- last Comment ends here -->
</div><!-- All Comments Ends here -->
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yT8Fc/

Comment: This solution is great but i can only use id in lastComment div as this is being used by my grails gsp tag which only updates the div with id only . So i hope if you have any idea to solve this problem using ID.

Comment: @KulveerSingh You can adapt the same code to use '#lastComment' instead of '.lastComment' and it will work "using ID," but you need to know that doing so is very, very wrong.

Comment: Thanks David. I will try. Please let me know how to give marks for your right answer .

Comment: David - only one thing is missing now, If i have two consecutive divs like allcomments_4 and allcomments_5  and i am updating lastcomment in allcomments_5 by using your code, it is still updating the allcomments_4 div . Any idea. why its not searching only within div of allcomments_5 .

Comment: @KulveerSingh The code that I provided should definitely limit the search to whatever number you pass in (my example passed a 4, and I assume you are passing a 5). That being said, check your code to make sure that you are properly closing all of your tags. In your example `commentEntry` is left open because the closing tag for `commentDate` is missing.

Comment: It all worked at last, Thank you for all and have a great weekend.